# How do I get the EPUB.js book.open() to work?

Tags: javascript, epub.js

I am developing a web extension where a user uploads a book in `epub` format to the client to parse.

To test my application, I have tried uploading several epub files but I can't seem to get past the `book.open()` function that is within my `handleFileSelection(event)` function.

I get the following error message:

```
GET https://www.fiverr.com/META-INF/container.xml 406
Failed to load book: {status: 406, message: 'Not Acceptable <br /><a href="https://www.fiverr.com/">Back</a>', stack: 'Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handler (chrome-extens…cokhmkcaamghhkkhdlgfbcnemijkdil/epub.js:15977:18)'}
```

The `container.xml` does not exist remotely and I believe this is what might be causing the issue.

Find below my code:

function handleFileSelection(event) {
const file = event.target.files[0]; // Get the selected file
const reader = new FileReader();

```
console.log('You are in handleFileSelection');

reader.onload = function (event) {
  console.log('You are inside reader.onload');
  const fileData = event.target.result; // Get the file data

  const meta = document.createElement('meta');
  meta.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'Content-Security-Policy');
  meta.setAttribute('content', "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'");
  document.head.appendChild(meta);

  const epubScript = document.createElement('script');
  epubScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('./epub.js');
  document.body.appendChild(epubScript);

  const jszipScript = document.createElement('script');
  jszipScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('./jszip.min.js');
  document.body.appendChild(jszipScript);

  const jszipUtilsScript = document.createElement('script');
  jszipUtilsScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('./jszip-utils.min.js');
  document.body.appendChild(jszipUtilsScript);
  Promise.all([
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      epubScript.onload = resolve;
    }),
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      jszipScript.onload = resolve;
    }),
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      jszipUtilsScript.onload = resolve;
    }),
  ])
    .then(() => {
      console.log('EPUB.js and JSZip libraries are loaded');

      const book = ePub();

      const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: 'text/plain' });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([fileData]));
      book.open(url, { containerPath: 'META-INF/container.xml' })
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`Book "${book.loaded.metadata.title}" loaded successfully`);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Failed to load book:', error);
        });

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Failed to load EPUB.js or JSZip:', error);
    });
};

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

}